# How do I plot a Histogram using Matplotlib for two variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram in python based on two columns ie State and Production. My dataframe looks like below:

```
State Year Area production
AB    2014 20000 21674
BS    2014 35000 116074
TS    2014 20000 32678
```

My requirement is to have States on x-axis and their production level at y-axis

Below is the code i have written:

```
%matplotlib inline
fig=plot.figure(figsize=(8,10))
ax=fig.gca()
Pulse_yield['State'].hist(x, bin =30)
ax.set_title('Yield in 2014')
ax.set_xlabel('States')
ax.set_ylabel('Production')
plot.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Issue is:  on x-axis, individual values are populating for each State but on y-axis , it is showing as 0,10,20,30, 40 etc and not the value I have in Production column.

[image: Histogram]

Comment: It looks like you want to plot a bar chart instead of a histogram.

Comment: The point is you cannot draw a histogram of two variables because a histogram shows the values on the x axis and the frequency of those values on the y axis.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.. Thanks for clarifying :) Could you please suggest which plot can be used for my purpose.

Comment: Yes, a `bar` plot. I marked this question as duplicate.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.. Could you please suggest how to do that .. or provide me the reference question for Bar Plot.

Comment: It's in the yellow box above the question. Also consider googling "pandas bar plot" or similar.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I got it finally!!!.. Thanks for helping out ..

Answer (score 0):

`plt.gca` gets the current axes, creating one if needed. It is only equivalent in the simplest 1 axes case.

The preferred way is to use `plt.subplots()` :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
```

or

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
```

and so on.